# Bash on Azure Pipeline running windows agent

Tags: bash, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get a build number from a secondary Azure pipeline. I'm using bash on a windows agent, already enabled developer mode, and installed the Linux feature. When I test this locally it works, I'm able to connect and get the build number but from the pipeline, I get the error...

> Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator

Could it be related to the Auth system token? I have also enabled "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token"

Bash code that I'm trying to use on the pipeline:

```html
#!/bin/bash

echo $TAG
echo $VER
echo $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN


echo "Executing call to get latest build from a pipeline definition Id"
echo "$URL-7.1"

export RESPONSE=`curl -u username":$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" --location --request GET "$URLapi-version=7.1-preview.1"`
echo $RESPONSE
export BUILD_NUMBER=`echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.["buildNumber"]'`
echo $BUILD_NUMBER
```

Powershell script working locally, but if I use this form, the access token is not recognized.

```html
$connectionToken= $(System.AccessToken)
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$BuildPipelineUrl = "$url`$top=1&api-version=6.0" 

Write-Host "URL: $BuildPipelineUrl"

$BuildPipelineInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BuildPipelineUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}) 


$ver = $BuildPipelineInfo.value.buildnumber

Write-Host "$ver"
```

Is there another way to use the Sys auth token, Do I have to convert it?

Thanks, everyone!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the following powershell script to check if it works.

```
$Token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
$BuildPipelineUrl = "$url`$top=1&api-version=6.0" 

Write-Host "URL: $BuildPipelineUrl"

$BuildPipelineInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BuildPipelineUrl -Method Get -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $Token" })
```